# Ambiguous Overloaded Constructor: C++

Tags: c++, matrix, constructor, default-constructor

I'm finishing up an assignment that has to do with matrix multiplication. We were given some skeleton files which I have filled; however I am dealing with an ambiguous constructor error, and the constructor must stay the same for the way it is graded:

test.cpp:6:7 error: call of overloaded 'Mat4()' is ambiguous

In my test code I want

```
Mat4 I; // to result in a call to SetIdentity() via the default constructor
I.Print( "I = " ); // should print the Identity Matrix for a 4x4
```

The relevant Mat4.h code:

```
class Mat4{
protected:
    float   m[4][4];

public:
    // ** 3A: **
Mat4( );
Mat4( float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0 );
```

And my Mat4.cpp code:

```
Mat4::Mat4( ){
SetIdentity( );
}

Mat4::Mat4( float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h,   float i, float j, float k, float l, float n, float o, float p, float q){
m[0][0] = a;
m[0][1] = b;
m[0][2] = c;
m[0][3] = d;
m[1][0] = e;
m[1][1] = f;
m[1][2] = g;
m[1][3] = h;
m[2][0] = i;
m[2][1] = j;
m[2][2] = k;
m[2][3] = l;
m[3][0] = n;
m[3][1] = o;
m[3][2] = p;
m[3][3] = q;
}
```

An example use of the non-default constructor:

```
Mat4
Mat4::operator*( Mat4& that ){
// "this" is a pointer to this class's mat4  (this->name)
// "that" is a reference to the other matrix (that.name)

Mat4 result(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int i, j, k;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            result.m[i][j] += (float)(this->m[i][k]*that.m[k][j]);
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know if you want to call `Mat4` with no arguments or with all defaulted arguments? You need to either remove the default constructor (and therefore always call `Mat4` with all zeroes), or have the first argument to the non-default constructor not have a default value (eg: `Mat4(float, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0);`) (note the first float doesn't have a default argument)

Comment: The second option worked and was very helpful, thanks! I had thought the compiler would be aware if 'Mat4' was given options or not, removing then non-default value fixed my issue.

Comment: @Steve Lorimer: In C++ terminology *both* of these constructors are *default* constructors. This is actually what caused the ambiguity in the first place: the OP declared a class with two default constructors, and the compiler does not know which one to use. Your second option suggests turning one default constructor into a non-default one.

Answer (score 1):

compiler can't distinguish constructor with no parameters at all `Mat4( )`; from constructor with all default parameters `Mat4(float=0,float=0... )`.
In the way you defined them it is ambiguous what constructor is needed to be invoked when you call Mat4( ).

**Naive solutions:**
1. you can add dummy parameter to your Mat4(), like Mat4(bool b) to resolve ambiguity
or
2. make first parameter in you constructor with many parameters non default

All this solutions deals with problem, but don't deals with cause of that problem.
The cause of the problem is an error in method design.

Update(suggested solution - **change methods design**):
such error shows that design of your class methods isn't good as needed.
so as @sth suggested, **use one constructor** instead of ambiguous 2.
all needed scenarios can be handled in the body of that constructor, so we get:

```
Matrix(float[] arr = 0, int sizeOfArray = 0)
{
  if (arr == 0)
    // use scenario which you used for Matrix()
  else // use scenario which you used for Matrix(float,float...)
}
```

**second variant**, instead of placing check in the body of constructor and choosing variant based on condition you can implement **choosing based on the overload resolution**:
when you need 2 constructors:

```
Matrix(float[] arr, int sizeOfArray)
Matrix()
```

Comment: 3. Maybe you don't need two separate constructors, maybe the one with all default arguments is enough.

Comment: @sth sure, it is enough, also signature should be changed, instead of  float,float,float... I would suggest (float[], int size)

Comment: Why do you suggest that?

Comment: @Oktalist because it is more general

Comment: `std::initializer_list` or a pair of iterators would be more general and avoid entering the mindset of a C programmer.

Comment: @Oktalist sure, thank you, I wrote my answer in mind with "C" tag, because code is in C style and not in C++ at all, only after you commented I looked at tags and saw "C++", I was quite surprised ))

Comment: C doesn't have constructors, or overloading.

Answer (score 0):

compiler doesn't know whether "Mat4( )" or
"Mat4( float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0, float=0 )" when you define "Mat4 I"